# Hibernate - Entity class Save(entity) method is not working

Tags: java, hibernate

Am trying to insert data into my database table "claim_grouping_history". But the Entity class .save(entity) method is not working.

`claimGroupingHistoryRepository.save(claimGroupingHistory);` this line is not working and there is not log information also.

Please find my model class :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@JsonInclude(NON_EMPTY)
@Table(name = "claim_grouping_history")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class ClaimGroupingHistory implements Serializable {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @JsonIgnore
      private Long id;


      @Column(name = "dealer_code")
      private String dealerCode;


      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false)
      private User createdBy;


      @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
      @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
      private DateTime createdAt;

      @Column(name = "last_updated_at")
      @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
      private DateTime lastModifiedAt;

}
```

Please find my Save method implementation:

```
    @Override
  @Transactional
  public void updateClaimGroupingKeyForDealer(String dealerId, GroupingKeyResource groupingKeyResource, String userId){

      User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);
      ClaimGroupingHistory claimGroupingHistory = null;
      System.out.println("History section---> if");
      claimGroupingHistory = new ClaimGroupingHistory();
      claimGroupingHistory.setDealerCode(dealerId);
      claimGroupingHistory.setCreatedAt(new DateTime());
      claimGroupingHistory.setCreatedBy(user);
      System.out.println("History section---> if"+claimGroupingHistory.toString());
      claimGroupingHistoryRepository.save(claimGroupingHistory);

  }
```

Please find my Repository class :

```
 public interface ClaimGroupingHistoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ClaimGroupingHistory, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ClaimGroupingHistory> {


    @Query("SELECT c FROM ClaimGroupingHistory c WHERE c.dealerCode = :dealer")
    ArrayList<ClaimGroupingHistory> getClaimGroupingHistory(@Param("dealer") String dealer);

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE ClaimGroupingHistory c SET c.createdBy = :createdBy, c.lastModifiedAt = :lastModifiedAt where c.dealerCode = :dealerCode")
    void updateClaimGroupingHistory(@Param("createdBy") User lastModifiedBy,@Param("lastModifiedAt") DateTime lastModifiedAt, @Param("dealerCode") String dealerCode);



}
```

Please find my persistance.xml file :

```
  <persistence-unit name="mysql-core" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="300"/>
      <property name="hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_soft_references" value="128"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show-sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Are you getting the correct user in that line `User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);`? I thought could be a problem in your repositories.

Comment: What's the sql generated by hibernate when you try to save? If isn't showing, update your `application.properties` with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and run it again.

Comment: There is no problem with UserRepository., its working fine.

Comment: @HenriqueMentz - I have updated my `persistance.xml` file in that file i have written `<property name="hibernate.show-sql" value="true"/>` and its not showing sql queries

Comment: When you use `xml`, you should to use `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>`. Fix it and try again, please. Look if you receive some log when you get the user in that line `User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);`.